# Mod Rewrite subdomain URL to root folder (apache)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I currently have a rewrite rule that rewrites *.domain.com to www.domain.com (except for blog.domain.com)

> RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com$1 [R=301,L]

I want to rewrite all my URLs from a subdomain to the root domain while keeping page name , adding the ".html" extension, and adding the [301] perm tag:

```
blog.domain.com/my-first-link  -->  www.domain.com/blog/my-first-link.html 
blog.domain.com/my-second-link -->  www.domain.com/blog/my-second-link.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/blog/$1.html [R=301,L]
```